# How to get Text and Icon in Turn By Turn Instruction in HERE SDK

Tags: android, routes, icons, here-api

I am working with HERE NOKIA SDK. I have gotten to create a route between 2 points and the voice instructions. Now I want to show the image arrow and the specfict text of the maneuver.

Comment: Hi @user2316075 , where you able to start Navigation with startNavigation `navigationManager.simulate()`?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK does not provide the icon of the turn. Please create some images to pair them against the maneuver turn type.

Also, the turn instruction fragments are provided by the com.here.android.routing.Maneuver class. Composing the fragments into a sentence is done by the app for localization reasons.

Comment: as i understand i need to call `navigationManager.getNextManeuver().getIcon()` in `onNewInstructionEvent` listener, than update my image based on result? so, i need to provide images for all types of image listed here - https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics_api_nlp/com-here-android-mpa-routing-maneuver-icon.html ?

Comment: Yes that is correct, you need to provide images to match against the list you have linked.